# How to kill POJO Data control Instance?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

I have a pojo data control "WagonDC" as given below:

```
package mobile.local;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import mobile.WagonEntity;

import oracle.adfmf.java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import oracle.adfmf.java.beans.ProviderChangeListener;
import oracle.adfmf.java.beans.ProviderChangeSupport;

public class WagonDC {

    private WagonEntity wagonEntity;
    private List wagonListDetails = new ArrayList();
    private WagonlistAdapter adapter = new WagonlistAdapter();

    public WagonDC() {
        super();
        System.out.println("----WAGON DC CALLED-----");
        findAll();
    }

    protected transient ProviderChangeSupport providerChangeSupport = new ProviderChangeSupport(this);

    public void addProviderChangeListener(ProviderChangeListener l) {
      providerChangeSupport.addProviderChangeListener(l);
    }

    public void removeProviderChangeListener(ProviderChangeListener l) {
       providerChangeSupport.removeProviderChangeListener(l);
    }


    public void setWagonEntity(WagonEntity wagonEntity) {
      this.wagonEntity = wagonEntity;
    }

    public WagonEntity getWagonEntity() {
      return wagonEntity;
    }

    public WagonEntity[] getWagonListDetails() {
        System.out.println("-------getWagonListDetails called-------");
      return (WagonEntity[]) wagonListDetails.toArray(new WagonEntity[wagonListDetails.size()]);
    }

    public void findAll() {
      wagonListDetails = adapter.findAllwagonList();
      if(wagonListDetails.size()>0){
          providerChangeSupport.fireProviderRefresh("wagonListDetails");
      }
    }

    public void refresh(){
        System.out.println("--Refreshing--");
        findAll();
        System.out.println("--Refreshed--");
    }

    public void update(WagonEntity wagonEntity) {
       boolean success = adapter.updateWagon(wagonEntity);
       if (success) {
         int index = wagonListDetails.indexOf(wagonEntity);
         wagonListDetails.set(index, wagonEntity);
       }
     }
}
```

This Data control is called first time when bindings on Wagons listing page loads, which looks like this:

```
<amx:listView var="row" value="#{bindings.wagonListDetails1.collectionModel}"
                                  fetchSize="#{bindings.wagonListDetails1.rangeSize}"
                                  selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.wagonListDetails1.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                                  initialScrollRowKeys="#{bindings.wagonListDetails1.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                                  selectionListener="#{bindings.wagonListDetails1.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                                  showMoreStrategy="autoScroll" bufferStrategy="viewport" id="lv2" >
        <amx:listItem id="li2">             
           <amx:outputText value="Wagon No: #{row.WAGON_NO}" id="ot19"/>
           <amx:outputText value="Product: #{row.PRD_DESC}" id="ot20"/>
        </amx:listItem>
</amx:listView>
```

Issue is when page loads second time, this time POJO Data control method "getWagonListDetails()" is not called. It looks like that the POJO DC creates an instance of a POJO the first time it is invoked in the Binding Context, and second time it displays data from previously created instance or device cache. But If I have some updated data then it doesn't shows on page. So I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to kill previous instance to load another new instance?
2. Does POJO stores data in cache, because if I close my application and re open then I can see updated values?
3. If data is stored in cache then is there any configuration setting to prevent data caching in Oracle MAF?

Note: I can manually refresh page data by calling "refresh()" method defined in POJO.

Answer (score 2):

actually the scope of a data control depends on where it is created. The configuration in the ApplicationController project makes it having a scope of application. Th configuration in the ViewController project will make it have a scope of Feature.

To answer your questions:

"Is there any way to kill previous instance to load another new instance?"

No and there is no need. Actually your sample queries the data within the constructor. You can call the query method from external as well. If data changes then you call a provider change event within the method that updates the list (collection) and the MAF framework will recognize itself that it has to refresh the UI to show the data changes.

"Does POJO stores data in cache, because if I close my application and re open then I can see updated values?"

As mentioned, the scope of the instance depends on where it is configured. The instance keeps the information until you change it or tell the instance to no longer remember it (by setting the list to an empty list)

"If data is stored in cache then is there any configuration setting to prevent data caching in Oracle MAF?"

As said, its an instance of your POJO class you create. All state is held in properties (the list in your case). So you can expose a method to nuke or refresh it and then - if you wanted to do something on transit - you use e.g. a method call activity to do what you want it to do.

Frank